# How to select particular action button for particular data which contains particular text

Tags: python, selenium, pageobjects

I have total for ex. 5 properties and action button for every property as shown in the picture. Each property has a status either manual or post. I need to find the property which has 'manual' status and click the action button for that corresponding property using selenium python page object model. I have thought about for and if loop but not coming to any conclusion. Kindly help.   [image: Table]
[image: html tags]
The first html tag is for the status 'Manual' or 'Post' and the second Tag is for action button. Like this 5 + 5 tags will be there for every property's status and action button.

I have tried for and if loop but not able to find the solution.

Comment: Add the `HTML` source for the elements,

Comment: I want to click the red color action button and process some functions for the data which has 'manually by you' status. So my code has to check which property (one is enough) has manual status and then click the red button.